# SQL querying group by

Tags: sql

Using the [w3schools database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), list order info for each country with following columns (see hint/notes in [] against each column) and sort the data in descending order by the TotalOrderAmount value.

•   Country
•   OrderCount [number of orders for each country]
•  ItemCount [sum of all the product quantities for each country]
•   TotalOrderAmount [total order value for all the orders for each country, rounded to two decimal points] 
•   AvgOrderSize [TotalOrderAmount / OrderCount, rounded to two decimal points]

I have the following skeleton but I'm stuck on how to group by country.. 
**EDITED - error 1: could not prepare statement (1 no such column:TotalOrderAmount)**

```
SELECT 
s.Country, COUNT(od.OrderID) AS OrderCount, sum(od.quantity) AS ItemCount, ROUND(sum(od.quantity*p.price),2) AS TotalOrderAmount, Avg(TotalOrderAmount/OrderCount)

FROM    Suppliers AS s

JOIN    Products AS p 
    ON p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
JOIN     OrderDetails AS od
    ON od.ProductID = p.ProductID
JOIN     Orders AS o
    ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID

Group by s.Country
```

Any help appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you get an error or unexpected output? Firstly I suggest you remove the trailing comma after `s.County,` rename `s.County` to `s.Country` and put something in those `sum()` aggregate functions

Comment: error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "2": syntax error)

Comment: and after you apply my suggested changes, what is the error?

Comment: Thank you @Nick.McDermaid, I made your suggested changes and they worked great. I started one by one again, but now I am stuck at the last piece. I made the edits above.

Comment: is this mysql or postgres?

Comment: @boyee, neither.. this is just using the database that is supplied from w3schools, so as long as the query works in the link above, then it's okay for now.

Comment: I guess `Avg(TotalOrderAmount/OrderCount)` is not valid, as there is no column called `TotalOrderAmount`. You need to substitute your expression for TotalOrderAmount (`ROUND(sum(od.quantity*p.price),2)`) into here as it doesn't exist as a column

Comment: And and there is not order count column either so you'll need to do the same for that.

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database implies that the database is SQLLite, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I suggest you remove the trailing comma after s.County, rename s.County to s.Country and put something in those sum() aggregate functions

I guess Avg(TotalOrderAmount/OrderCount) is not valid, as there is no column called TotalOrderAmount. You need to substitute your expression for TotalOrderAmount (ROUND(sum(od.quantity*p.price),2)) into here as it doesn't exist as a column

And and there is not order count column either so you'll need to do the same for that

Answer (score -1):

In the group by you have to include all the columns in your query.

Comment: No. You only include the columns you need and you do not include any columns in aggregate functions.

Comment: if you use postgres, thats the way i see.But in mysql you only set the one you need.